# Apache DocumentRoot won't change

Tags: linux, debian, apache

I am trying to change the DocumentRoot in httpd.conf from `/var/www` to `/var/www/shop` just so I can be organized. But even when I do that after restarting apache and httpd, I go to localhost and it still points to `/var/www`. My httpd.conf is basically the same as this file here:

http://www.devside.net/guides/config/linux/httpd-conf

I am running this on Debian.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian uses various include files and a "site" concept, so httpd.conf isn't normally changed at all (the includes are). You likely changed the value *before* the "default" site changes it back to `/var/www`.

Comment: Yes, even if you've changed the default config, look for Include directives in httpd.conf. One of them might be overriding your change.